# Join on one date entry in one table being the closest date to another entry in another table

Tags: sql

I am trying to basically reconcile two separate payment tables I have, one that bases the payments off when the payment was actually made, and the other that has the payment when it was actually processed. Some brain genius decided that it wouldn't be a great idea for both of these tables to have some unique ID that could join together so I've had to take the long way around. I imagine this involves joining both tables using a subquery but I have no idea how to write it. Here are the tables and I'll explain what I want to do a bit more afterwards

**`payment` table**

```
account_id           payment_refID        payment_date        Amount 
000001               AAA                  01/01/2019          5.00
000001               BBB                  03/01/2019          5.00
000001               CCC                  05/01/2019          5.00
000001               DDD                  31/01/2019          5.00
000001               EEE                  02/02/2019          5.00
000001               FFF                  28/02/2019          5.00
000001               GGG                  05/03/2019          5.00
```

**`transaction` table**

```
account_id2          payment_refID        payment_date        Amount 
000001               111                  08/01/2019          5.00
000001               222                  10/01/2019          5.00
000001               333                  12/01/2019          5.00
000001               444                  08/02/2019          5.00
000001               555                  15/02/2019          5.00
000001               666                  03/03/2019          5.00
000001               777                  12/03/2019          5.00
```

here's how my code looks so far

```
SELECT *
from  payments a
join trasnaction b
on a.account_id = b.account_id2
and a.amount = b.amount
and [b.transactiondate is the closest transaction date after a.transactiondate. This is what I need help with]
```

so basically when I join up the tables I would want it to look like this:

The join would basically be 1:1 in the example above with payment ref AAA matching up to 111 and BBB matching up to 222

I would not be able to just join on the dates being a week after since some payments may get processed quicker or slower and there might be multiple payments on the same day. Any help is appreciated

Comment: in this case what is id after `999`??? in both `table`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: are you sure there is not a table somewhere with a relation between `payments.payment_refID` and `transactions.payment_refID`?

Comment: In your example AAA, BBB and CCC will all match 111 instead of 111, 222 and 333, so if you have not rules on how to join the tables.. simply you can't. If the "distance" between payment and transaction is at least one week.. you can refine the search but you will not be sure at 100% you can get wrong results

Answer (score 0):

If you have not a relationship between `payments.payment_refID` and `transactions.payment_refID` you will have big troubles.

In your example AAA, BBB and CCC will all match 111 instead of 111, 222 and 333, so if you have not rules on how to join the tables.. simply you can't.

If the "distance" between payment and transaction is fixed (ie one week).. you can refine the search, but you will not be sure at 100% because you can get wrong results for payments made in the same day.

The only solution is to assume that `payment_refID` in both tables is in ascending order and that each transaction is related to its payment in cronological order.
So you can number all payments and all transactions and join them on that counter.

In Microsoft SQL Server you can try this:

```
;with
p as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by p.account_id order by p.payment_date, p.payment_refID) n
    from payments p 
),
t as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t.account_id2 order by t.payment_date, t.payment_refID) n
    from transactions t
)
select *
from p
join t on p.account_id = t.account_id2 and p.n = t.n
```